# Can I use Nexus lanes to enter Canada with expired Nexus Card?

Tags: canada, nexus

My Nexus card expires soon.  While submitted my renewal application a few months ago, the US CBP warns:

> Due to a significant increase in application volume, we are extending
>   the grace period from 6 months to 1 year for any submitted renewal
>   application. This means you will continue to receive full benefits for
>   1 year while U.S. Customs and Border Protection is finalizing your
>   renewal application.

I haven't found similar assurances about entering Canada using the Nexus lanes.

I searched through the CBP Trusted Traveler sites as well as the Canada Border Services Agency, but the only information I've found indicates that as far as Canada is concerned, Nexus is only valid through the expiration date https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/new-nouvel-eng.html

The similar question on StackExchange only covers US entry, not entry to Canada.

So, if my Nexus card expires before my next trip to BC, does the US CBP assurance that I have a one-year grace period also apply to using the Nexus lanes to enter Canada?

Comment: The answer must come from Canadian immigration authorities, not US CBP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as a renewal application has been submitted, Canada honors the use of expired Nexus card within the grace period, currently 12 months.

I called Canadian Border Services today. Annoyed, they said yes, that is what a grace period is. So, while there is no indication on Canadian Border Services websites that they will honor the grace period, they verbally affirmed that they do.